# Need to cast the class object with parent class's parent object in java

Tags: java, c#, generics, casting

I need to cast the class object with parent class's parent object in java and same behavior is working in C#.

In C# I can cast the class object to parent class's parent object.

C# Code:
[image]

In java I cant achieve this behavior.

Java Code:
[image]

How to achieve this in java?.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, [do not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) of your code. Instead copy paste it directly in your question as text

Comment: Don't post pictures of code, post *actual code* please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic type parameters in Java are *invariant*. That means `Iterable<Cat>` is not a subtype of `Iterable<Species>` (nor vice versa) even though `Cat` is a subtype of `Species`.

C# allows the generic type to declare its type parameters as invariant, covariant, or contravariant. If you declare `Foo<out T>`, it will be covariant, i.e. `Foo<A>` is a subtype of `Foo<B>` if `A` is a subtype of `B`; and if you declare `Foo<in T>`, it will be contravariant, i.e. `Foo<B>` is a subtype of `Foo<A>` if `A` is a subtype of `B`. `IEnumerable` is declared with its type parameter being covariant (i.e. with `<out T>`, so `IEnumerable<Cat>` can be a subtype of `IEnumerable<Species>`.

Covariance and contravariance is achieved in Java using wildcards. `? extends` wildcards are covariant, while `? super` wildcards are contravariant. There is the **PECS** rule (Producer `extends`, Consumer `super`) that guides you in using them. The `Iterable` interface is effectively a producer of its type parameter `T` (it has a method which returns an `Iterator<T>`, which in turn has a method which returns a `T`; and there are no methods that take a `T` as an argument); therefore, it should always be used with a `? extends` wildcard. So you should use `Iterable<? extends Something>` instead of `Iterable<Something>`.

So if you declare `Animal` like this:

```
abstract class Animal extends Species {
    public Iterable<? extends Cat> elements();
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Iterable<? extends Species> childNodes;

childNodes = (currentElement != null) ? currentElement.elements() : null;
```

By the way, the `IEnumerable` interface in C# is likewise effectively a producer of its type parameter, and that's why they declared it as covariant.

Answer (score -1):

Java and C# are different, let me explain you with the code:

```
package test;
class A {
    {
        System.out.println(1);
    }
}
class B extends A {
    {
        System.out.println(2);
    }
}
class C extends B {
    {
        System.out.println(3);
    }
}
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A c = new C();
    }
}
```

Here we can make the object of parent class and instantiate or initialize that object with the child class but reverse is not true.
i.e C c = new A();

This line will throw java.lang.ClassCastException.

It is because in java the child class can use the methods of the parent class but the parent class cannot use the methods of the child class in general, but there are some tricks which can serve this purpose.

In general one can use the things of there parents but parents are not allowed to use the things of the children, you can think it like that.